# Mysql - How can I subtract the number of rows returned by 2 queries

Tags: mysql

in trying to learn MySQL, I've been solving the problems from Hackerrank. I've got stuck at [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-4/problem), which asks:

> "*[...]find the difference between the total number of CITY entries in the table and the number of distinct CITY entries in the table.*"

The idea is to output a single answer `N' - N`.

The schema looks like this:

[image]

To this effect, the query I've tried is:

```
select count(s2.c2) - count(s1.c1) 
from (select city as c1 from station group by city) as s1, 
(select city as c2 from station) as s2;
```

I've also tried many other variants, but none of them give me the right answer. Where am I going wrong? I've also looked up other questions on SO but they do not return a *single* number.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `count(distinct)`, and no need to use self-join, try following:

```
select
    count(city) - count(distinct city)
from station
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of doing this. To use your direction:

```
select total_cities - count(distinct_cities) 
from (select count(*) as distinct_cities from station group by city) as s1, 
(select count(*) as total_cities from station) as s2
GROUP BY total_cities;
```

So first counting the `distinct_cities` to have just a unique list, you could also use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city AS distinct_cities FROM station
```

And then counting the total number of distinct cities by counting these again in the outer query. Hope this helps you to think of more (shorter) ways of writing this.

Comment: I think you meant `distinct_cities - total_cities`? Actually, it should be the other way, or I should wrap an `abs(...)` around it. Okay, thanks. Let me try this.

Comment: I interpretated your question as the total count of the distinct (ie uniquely named) cities, then it would be the count, and you would end up with a single value out this query. Else it would become a list with the count for a given city (lets say Amsterdam is 5 times in the list, so 5) minus the total of lets say 100 cities. Then Londen 3 times in the list, minus 100 etc. (The question leaves a little bit of space for interpretation there)

Comment: Yeah, you interpreted it right. But when I tried to run your code, it said `ERROR 1140 (42000) at line 5: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 's2.total_cities'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` So I assumed that was a typo. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah, that is the setting of mysql: I used the non-ansi style: I will update the issue with an ANSI compliant query

Comment: Sure, as a tip for future readers it would be helpful... you already have my upvote. Cheers :)